# Fail to use custom model in tensorflow lite object detection android app

Tags: android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I trained model using Google AutoMl then produce tensorflow lite model to detect plastic bottle etc. I would like to use in the tensorflowlite object detection android example but failed

this the github that i refer : https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android

i replaced the tflite file and the txt file with my own project, the installation on android studio its work well but the apps its crashed and didnt work

```
public class DetectorActivity extends CameraActivity implements OnImageAvailableListener {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = new Logger();

  // Configuration values for the prepackaged SSD model.
  private static final int TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE = 300;
  private static final boolean TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED = true;
  private static final String TF_OD_API_MODEL_FILE = "swai.tflite";
  private static final String TF_OD_API_LABELS_FILE = "file:///android_asset/swai.txt";
  private static final DetectorMode MODE = DetectorMode.TF_OD_API;
  // Minimum detection confidence to track a detection.
  private static final float MINIMUM_CONFIDENCE_TF_OD_API = 0.5f;
  private static final boolean MAINTAIN_ASPECT = false;
  private static final Size DESIRED_PREVIEW_SIZE = new Size(640, 480);
  private static final boolean SAVE_PREVIEW_BITMAP = false;
  private static final float TEXT_SIZE_DIP = 10;
  OverlayView trackingOverlay;
```

this the eror that i found when deploying in the virtual devices

```
09-17 13:32:09.283 1599-1856/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 462848
09-17 13:32:09.325 9980-10000/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 9980
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 786432 bytes and a ByteBuffer with 270000 bytes.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfShapeIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:272)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfDataIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:249)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.setTo(Tensor.java:110)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:151)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:275)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:193)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity$2.run(DetectorActivity.java:181)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

I think there is no settings to implement this model work, Any Sugesstion please? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ali, could you please add the error logcat in the question? That would make it easier for us to figure out what the error could be.

Comment: @BennyHawk Thanks for reply, i already add the error logcat..

Comment: What was the input shape for your model which you trained with AutoML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

case close, solved with changing the TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE from 300 to 512. 786432 is represent 512x512x3 but my input is only 270000 (300x3003).